# Add rounded corners in border in Maps Fragment and remove the Fragment background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have added a border in Maps fragment. The corners are rounded too. But the problem is that the fragment background is still appearing in the corners. It just makes the whole design look odd. Can this be overcome? I am also attaching a screenshot of my problem that is occurring in my App. So I would appreciate any kind of help in this regard.

---

Here is the map code which I have used to implement the design explained in my question, so that the problem can be well understood.

```
**activity_maps.xml:**

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/map_border_2"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
Code for implementing the borders is given Below.

**map_border_2.xml (Drawable file):**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:gradientRadius="2dp" />
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/glass"
                android:width="10dp" />
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

In the above code, I need to remove the map fragment background from the four corners. I have added some buttons on the map but I have no issue in that!
```

---

[image: **Screenshot**]

The Above image is the output of my code. In the above image, need to remove the places with circles.

Comment: remove this line android:background="@drawable/map_border_2" from linear layout and add it in relativelayout. got it? or i need to add answer? let me know

Comment: I have done it before. But if you that you can see that the design is not loading.

Comment: put your layour inside carview and apply radius for cardview

Comment: Relative Layout inside CardView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add this line to `RelativeLayout` or `fragment`

`android:background="@drawable/map_border_2"`

I hope it will work with you

Comment: The design comes and disappears!